# Is there a good way to print the time after each run with `mocha -w`?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I like letting `mocha -w` run in a terminal while I work on test so I get immediate feedback, but I can't always tell from a glance if it's changed or not when the status doesn't change - did it run, or did it get stuck  (it's happened)?

I'd like to have a way to append a timestamp to the end of each test run, but ideally only when run in 'watch' mode - if I'm running it manually, of course I know if it ran or not.

For now, I'm appending an asynchronous console log to the last test that runs:

```
it('description', function () {
  // real test parts.should.test.things();
  // Trick - schedule the time to be printed to the log - so I can see when it was run last
  setTimeout(() => console.log(new Date().toDateString() + " @ " + new Date().toTimeString()), 5);
});
```

Obviously this is ugly and bad for several reasons:

- It's manually added to the last test - have to know which that is
- It is added every time *that* test is run, but never others - so if I run a different file or test -> no log; if I run only that test manually -> log
- It's just kind of an affront to the purpose of the tests - subverting it to serve my will

I have seen some references to mocha adding a `global.it` object with the command line args, which could be searched for the '-w' flag, but that is even uglier, and still doesn't solve most of the problems.

Is there some other mocha add-in module which provides this? Or perhaps I've overlooked something in the options? Or perhaps I really shouldn't need this and I'm doing it all wrong to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha supports [root level hooks](https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks). If you place an `after` hook (for example) outside any `describe` block, it should run at the end of all tests. It won't run only in watch mode, of course, but should otherwise be fit for purpose.

Comment: Yeah, a root-level 'after' better accomplishes the task - works regardless of which tests are run (as long as its file is loaded). Thanks!